# Temporary data storage in django which is persistent across browser

Tags: django, database, django-sessions

I'm building a Django where the admin will create a user and then one mail will be sent to the user. In the mail, I'm also sending one token with the URL on clicking which the user will get verified by checking the correctness of the token.

But the problem is I'm storing the token in *Django session* and when I open the link on the same browser it works but on a different machine user is not getting verified as session data becomes unavailable.
Someone suggest me the best way to store the token.

I didn't want to use the database as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: So, admin user creates a user and sends a link to another user. The other user clicks on this and gets verified? Did I get your flow correctly? I don't see why this would not go in the database. If you want to make it temporary, delete the token from the DB when the user clicks on the verification link.

Comment: Yeah you got it. But the thing is that for storing a token we have to create a field in user model or a separate model. Actually I got the solution [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/django-user-registration-with-email-confirmation#:~:text=First%20we%20need%20to%20configure,in%20the%20settings.py%20file.&text=We%20used%20the%20email%2Did,other%20SMTP%20server%20as%20well.)

Comment: Any particular reason why adding a field/separate model is out of the question?

Comment: just a developer thing